# iOS Swift - How to use Facebook Sign Up and Login

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

This is a very high level architectural question.

I want to use "Sign Up with Facebook" and "Log in with Facebook" in my iOS app.

Questions:

1. I find many tutorials for logging in with Facebook but I am not getting anything for Sign Up with Facebook, like a tutorial for "SignUp with Facebook".
2. How can I use Sign Up with Facebook in my app? As in, what will be the architecture? What do I need to send to my server? What I need to store about the user in my server's DB?

After checking Spotify's "SignUp with Facebook" my understanding is, when the user clicks on Sign up with Facebbok, he is still asked with Facebook login but the SignUp screen will get pre-filled with some basic information like phone, email, first and last name etc, which I can use on my app to sign up the user.

Next time when the user logs in using facebook I just validate if he has already signup or not

Am I thinking right? any corrections? feedback?

Comment: I want to let the user SignUp on my app using Facebook, basically how Spotify does

Comment: The Facebook SDK [uses the same button to represent both concepts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.4). I'm not sure why the OP wants to do something different.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Facebook login for the sole purpose of it being an easy way to get your users to sign up/log in to your app, then your app will be rejected by Apple. You need to be using Facebook application features that go beyond just basic profile information and sharing.

I just went through this during the Apple App Store review process and think it's worth noting here. A little warning to those who think they will save time.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the user's profile and info, plus a userId i think. 
Then you can add the user's Facebook id as userID, Facebook email as username, and a very long pre-defined string as it's password.

This is totally secure as long as the very long pre-defined password is not public. Only your server (or your app) will have that and will put that as password when you log in.

The username will be the Facebook email, which is straight forward. And the userId in your database will be the Facebook id that you get from your login session.

All the data can be read from the FBSDKProfile, when login is successful.

Hope it helps :)

p.s. you can also use Digits by Twitter, it is an awesome SDK for signing in with phone verification.